# Why can't iterable unpacking be used in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

When I try to unpack lists in a list comprehension:

```
[*parent.rules for parent in parents if hasattr(parent, "rules")]
```

I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension
```

While I understand there are other ways to do this, this seems like the most obvious and Pythonic way. Why does Python disallow this behaviour?

Comment: why are you unpacking `parent`?  What type is it?

Comment: I'd recommend removing all that stuff about your metaclass from the question and just ask about the unpacking. As you can see, people are confused about the irrelevant part of your question.

Comment: PEP 448 mentions that this might be allowed the future. In the meantime, you can use `chain.from_iterable(parent.rules for parent in parents if hasattr(parent, "rules"))`. (I might use `getattr(parent, "rules", [])` in this case to avoid the condition.)

Comment: @Ry Thanks for marking my question as a duplicate - might it be better to give the original question a better name so people can find it more easily?

Comment: @TheInitializer: People can find it through your question now =) That’s the point of duplicates.